# Javascript - NaN

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to do a small calculation to find the Markup of a product. How ever I am getting a 'NaN' error in my console. Obviously I know this means Not a Number but I can't figure out how to fix the error.

```
function calculateSuggestedCost() {
    var suggestedCost = 0;
    var idealGP = $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_ideal_gp').val;
    var cost = $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_cost').val;

    suggestedCost = parseFloat(cost /(1 - idealGP));


     $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_suggested_price').val(suggestedCost);   

}

//    =Cost/(1-Margin Percentage)
```

I've tried using parseFloat but I'm guessing the way I've used it isn't quite right.

---

Thank's for all the quick replies. Modification of Joe Frambach's answer just to show my final working solution for anyone else looking.

```
function calculateSuggestedCost() {
    var suggestedCost = 0;
    var idealGP = parseFloat($('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_ideal_gp').val());
    var cost = parseFloat($('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_cost').val());

    suggestedCost = Math.round(cost /(1 - (idealGP/100)));
    $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_suggested_price').val(suggestedCost);
    calculateActualGP();
}
```

Comment: maybe you should use `val()` instead of `val`

Comment: `.val` is a function. Use `$([selector]).val()`;

Comment: It's actually one of the few thing's I already knew, I just forgot to put them. Thank you all for your swift replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery `val` is a function. You need `()` to call a function:

```
var idealGP = $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_ideal_gp').val();
var cost = $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_cost').val();
```

Also, when reading numbers from an external source, it is best to convert to numbers and do validation *immediately*, not during your calculation:

```
var idealGP = parseFloat($('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_ideal_gp').val());
var cost = parseFloat($('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_cost').val());

suggestedCost = cost /(1.0 - idealGP); // now you can assume that everything is numbers.
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `.value` is the native JS property and could be accessed via `$('#element')[0].value` or `$('#element').get(0).value` - just `.val` on its own is never valid

Comment: Regular js dom is `.value`, not `.val`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.val It does some sanity checking and basically just returns `ret = elem.value;`.

Comment: Can't believe that was all it was, sometimes its the smallest of things hah. I'll accept your answer in 5 min's as soon as it lets me. Now I just need to work out why my calculation is wrong.

Comment: I've added some comments

Answer (score 1):

when your are trying to get the value from some it or so use `.val(). not val`

```
 var idealGP = $('#bc_inventorybundle_dish_ideal_gp').val();
```